# Functions drop the custom class of my tibble

Tags: r, tibble

```
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'tidyverse' was built under R version 3.4.2
#> ── Attaching packages ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.2.1 ──
#> ✔ ggplot2 2.2.1     ✔ purrr   0.2.4
#> ✔ tibble  1.4.2     ✔ dplyr   0.7.4
#> ✔ tidyr   0.8.0     ✔ stringr 1.2.0
#> ✔ readr   1.1.1     ✔ forcats 0.2.0
#> Warning: package 'tibble' was built under R version 3.4.3
#> Warning: package 'tidyr' was built under R version 3.4.3
#> Warning: package 'purrr' was built under R version 3.4.2
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.4.2
#> ── Conflicts ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
#> ✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
#> ✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()

tmp <- as_tibble(mtcars) %>% structure(class = c(class(.), "other_class"))

class(tmp)
#> [1] "tbl_df"      "tbl"         "data.frame"  "other_class"

tmp %>% arrange(mpg) %>% class()
#> [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

How can I allow for any other function to preserve this `other_class`? I'm aware of [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/155) and [this](https://github.com/tidyverse/tibble/issues/275) but I can't seem to get my head around it. Any hints?

Comment: the second link is definitely the one to worry about

Comment: While it gets sorted out, you could make your own S3 methods for dplyr verbs that remove and re-add the class, e.g. `arrange.other_class <- function(.data, ...){structure(arrange(structure(.data, class = class(.data)[class(.data) != 'other_class']), ...), class = class(.data))}` Obviously that's not ideal, though. Also, your class should be listed first, presuming you want it to take priority when methods exist.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.